# How can i identify a view in objective c with given nativeID(given in react-native)

Tags: objective-c, react-native

In React-Native i have a component like this

```
<View nativeID={'id1'}>
 ...other chicle components
</View>
```

In native how this nativeID will be used.
In Objective C how can i check if certain UIVIew has given nativeID or not.
I have access to RCTRootView, now how can i get a subview with given nativeID.

Comment: Iterate over all your subviews and check their `nativeID` value.

Comment: Property 'nativeID' not found on object of type 'UIView *'

Comment: Did you add `#import "UIView+React.h"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `nativeID` for all subviews as follows:

```
#import "UIView+React.h"

for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
    if [subview.nativeID isEqualToString: "myIDString"] {
        // found it!
    }
}
```

Comment: #import "UIView+React.h" is must.

Comment: i got error UIView+React.h not found

Comment: Same here and also I got error for self.subviews in the .m file