# React native: How to select a view element with nativeID

Tags: react-native

In React Native I have a component like this,

```
<View nativeID="myView" />
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#nativeid

Now, how can I call/select this View with **myView** id?

I've checked this: [How can i identify a view in objective c with given nativeID(given in react-native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706413/how-can-i-identify-a-view-in-objective-c-with-given-nativeidgiven-in-react-nati)

But unfortunately this isn't work for me.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since I started with React and even react native I never had to use a field like your nativeID. Instead, react and react-native allow the use of references. Many times while coding it is used something like:

```
this.doSomething_specified()
```

Well, it is possible to pass the reference "this" as prop while using a React component:

```
<MyReactComp called={this} ... />
```

and use methods or functions related to "this" within the declaration of  MyReactComp .

Comment: Thank you. But could you please provide an example. I don't understand how to implement this from your answer. I just need to call a specific `<View />` component and get it's x-y co-ordinate positions.

Comment: Please, look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216325/reactnative-get-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-relative-to-the-screen?rq=1

Comment: Actually, this is to get the position of element on loading. But I need the position of element after dragging end. This is exactly what I need. Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63924996/react-native-get-actual-x-y-co-ordinates-of-an-element-after-finish-dragging-r

Comment: I used the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable and this one talks about the onDragRelease callback. What you are asking might be related to the component you are using. So, I suggest you to write to the respective creators (issues section of their github) and tell them which call back and props to use.

Comment: Thanks for your reference. I actually posted there. https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/1192 But no response :( Could you please confirm me that I could do what I want here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63924996/react-native-get-actual-x-y-co-ordinates-of-an-element-after-finish-dragging-r with your suggested https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable package?

Comment: The best answer I found is located at: https://github.com/tongyy/react-native-draggable/issues/77

Comment: https://github.com/tongyy/react-native-draggable/issues/52